# Is it possible for users to generate a dump of their questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, data-dump

I'm wondering if it is possible - like for instance *Twitter* provides - to generate a dump of the content a user has produced on the website?

There are - if I recall correctly - regular dumps of the entire website one can download. But the problem is that it results in more than 20 GiB of content and most users are only interested in a tiny fraction of it: front-end web programmers are probably not interested in hardware programming in `C`.

It would be nice if there was some kind of dump generator tool where one can decide (for instance, by tags, users, etc.) to generate a dump of the content.

Comment: See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176293/how-do-i-export-my-questions-and-answers) on [meta.se].

Answer (score 4):

I quickly created this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1346952?UserId=67579) for you.

It simply does a union over posts, comments and edit posthistory where you're the owner. SEDE does have an export to CSV option so you click that and have a local/offline storage of content you contributed.

```sql
select 'Q' [Type]
     , id
     , parentid
     , creationdate
     , body
     , title
     , tags
from posts
where owneruserid = ##userid?67579##
and posttypeid = 1 -- Q
union 
select 'A' [Type]
     , p.id
     , p.parentid
     , p.creationdate
     , p.body
     , q.title
     , q.tags
from posts p
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
where p.owneruserid = ##userid?67579##
and p.posttypeid = 2 -- A
union
select 'C' [Type]
     , c.id
     , c.postid
     , c.creationdate
     , c.text
     , q.title
     , q.tags
from comments c
inner join posts p on p.id = c.id
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
where c.userid = ##userid?67579##
union
select 'E' [Type]
     , ph.id
     , ph.postid
     , ph.creationdate
     , case when ph.posthistorytypeid in (5,8) then text else null end
     , case when ph.posthistorytypeid in (4,7) then text else null end
     , case when ph.posthistorytypeid in (6,9) then text else null end
from posthistory ph
inner join posts p on p.id = ph.postid
inner join posts q on q.id = coalesce(p.parentid, p.id)
where ph.userid = ##userid?67579##
and ph.posthistorytypeid in (4,5,6, 7,8,9) -- edits and rollbacks
```

As [indicated by Jon Clements](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269697/is-it-possible-for-users-to-generate-a-dump-of-their-questions-answers/403632?noredirect=1#comment813991_403632), if you are after **ALL** your data that you ever submitted to SE, including stuff that is not in SEDE, you can do a [GDPR request](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request). As a response you'll receive a file that has all your data in it. Everything. I haven't personally requested that ever so I can't comment on its usability but based on [Can a GDPR request take up to a month to process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336713/can-a-gdpr-request-take-up-to-a-month-to-process) I learn that:

> The GDPR requires that the information you provide to an individual is in a concise, transparent, intelligible and easily accessible form, using clear and plain language.

as quoted by user [GhostCat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/285661/ghostcat)

Comment: For where you're after your own content - it's also possible to make a [GDPR request](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/gdpr/request) - it can take a little while but it's certainly comprehensive in what you receive from it.

Comment: (my memory is a little rusty but fairly sure it included in addition to Q&A things such as chat messages, flags raised, comments made, login times, your profile history etc... can't seem to find the file I had from April last year to check... but also fairly sure it was across *all* sites you have an account on as well...)